# How to split a string with a series of regexes and maintain the string's original ordering?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string that can contain specific text which needs to be altered.  How can I take the paragraph in as a string and perform a string split containing a series of regular expressions while keeping the text that does not need altered as well.

As of right now I have a regular expression that is extracting the text that needs altered, but leaving the rest out.

```
var regex = /[A-Z]+-[0-9]+[\s]+specificText+[\s]+[0-9)]+[\s]+|specificText[\s]+[0-9]+/gi
var str = "KJSDHFS345  KJSDHFS345      BLAH-3242352    specificText      456    specificText     564     SAUHAUH&^%  SAUHAUH&^%"
str.match(regex);
```

Currently, I am receiving the following array as a result:

```
["BLAH-3242352    specificText      456    ", "specificText     564"]
```

However, I am looking for a way to have an array like this returned:

```
["KJSDHFS345  KJSDHFS345      ", "BLAH-3242352    specificText      456    ", "specificText     564", "     SAUHAUH&^%  SAUHAUH&^%"]
```

How can I make the array maintain the original ordering of the paragraph, regardless of what characters are contained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use `split` rather than `match`: *capture* the substrings you want, and they'll be separated from the non-matching parts, while including everything in the resulting array:

```js
var regex = /([A-Z]+-[0-9]+[\s]+specificText+\s+[0-9)]+\s+|specificText\s+[0-9]+)/i
var str = "KJSDHFS345  KJSDHFS345      BLAH-3242352    specificText      456    specificText     564     SAUHAUH&^%  SAUHAUH&^%"
console.log(str.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

(note that a character class that has only a single token is superfluous; you can use just that single token instead, and no global flag needed when `split`ting)

If you *had* to use `match`, I guess an ugly method would be to alternate your original pattern with `<any characters which aren't the start of a match to the original pattern>`:

```js
var regex = /[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\s+specificText+\s+[0-9)]+\s+|specificText\s+[0-9]+|(?:(?![A-Z]+-[0-9]+\s+specificText+\s+[0-9)]+\s+|specificText\s+[0-9]+).)+/gi
//                                                                            ^^^^^^^ ...
var str = "KJSDHFS345  KJSDHFS345      BLAH-3242352    specificText      456    specificText     564     SAUHAUH&^%  SAUHAUH&^%"
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

But I wouldn't recommend it - the `split` method is much easier to read and write.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks

Comment: Do you need `g` in `/gi`? Do you need to put `\s` in character classes? (Sorry, I know little of Javascript, but know that neither are needed in some languages.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland You're right, no need for those, that simplifies things a bit